# How to build an "instantaneous" clamper circuit

Tags: diode-clamp, clamp

I am asked to clamp a signal 5sin(ωt) V with frequency of 1 kHz to a DC level of 2 V and -4 V. I already built circuits that can do that. But my professor says that the graphs should be exactly like the ones in the figure. What I mean by this is that, as it is shown in the graphs, the voltage should be clamped to the DC level since time 0 (or almost). He says that the graph in LTspice should look just like the ones in blue. How do I do that with a clamper circuit? Is this even possible? (I can only use resistors, capacitors and normal diodes, like 1N4004 and a voltage source).
He is not talking about having the capacitor already loaded at t = 0.

[image: Clamper circuit to 2V]

[image: Current output of my clamper circuit]

[image: Graph]

[image]

Comment: This is not a homework solution service. You need to make a significant effort to solve this yourself, and show us all of your work.

Comment: "*... the one in blue ...*" There are two in blue. Please [edit] and add captions (Fig. 1, 2, 3, 4) and refer to them by label in your text to avoid confusion.

Comment: Add `uic` to the simulation card, something like this: `.tran 10m uic`.

Comment: The way I would do it for a Video signal with a negative sync tip and positive video is detect the plateau or zero crossing in your case then using one shot , short the AC coupled signal to the Vdc you choose.  In your case he wants to to assume no load and thus 0V drop after the diode conducts 0 current after charging to the defined positive or negative clamp voltage + or - the peak sine wave.  So +/-5Vp clamped at -3V results in an average of +2V, although your Prof is using the wrong term, the clamp voltage is -3 or +7 for neg or positive clamps with a 10Vpp swing.

Comment: Both in Blue are unclamped.  And clamping depends on where you sample.  Add that to your schematic.  **I already built circuits that can do that.**   Are you sure?  Maybe you should be teaching the class!

Comment: I'm confused by the terminology you're using and the graphs you've shown. To me, 'clamping' means that you're imposing some maximum or minimum limit, past which the signal will not be allow to go. What you're showing in the red vs blue graphs looks more like level shifting, where you're adjusting the DC offset of a 10Vp-p AC signal.

Comment: `I can only use resistors, capacitors and normal diodes, like 1N4004.` You appear to be using a voltage source as well.

Comment: @brhans I think this terminology is followed in many textbooks. This is how we were also taught. The maximum limiting circuits were called *clipper* circuits. They cut the signal. Clamper Circuits also limit maximum value, but by shifting the signal instead of cutting it.

Comment: seeing as this is a simulation start C1 with a charge of 2V in it, or ask the simulator to find a stable state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clamping (ie, voltage limiting) happening on the blue traces shown as example, so I guess what you're asked is to add a DC offset to your AC signal. In this case, no need for a diode. Just AC-couple the AC through a cap and use a resistor for the DC.

[image]

This does not solve the other problem, which is that the teacher doesn't understand that LTSpice calculates the operating point before running the transient simulation, which means the capacitor will be charged to the correct voltage right at the start, which of course never happens with real devices because when you turn the thing on... well, it was off so all capacitors are at 0V.

Comment: I'm not sure V4 is allowed under the OP's component resitrictions.

Comment: This is not an  instantaneous clamp.

Comment: I assumed the "clamp" thing was a mistranslation and what he really wanted was the blue signals on the screenshots.

Comment: or just put V2 in series with V1